# A list of $v$ of one vector $v \in V$ is linear independent if and only if $v\ \neq 0$

Tags: linear-algebra

Why a list of $v$ of one vector $v \in V$ is linear independent if and only if $v\ \neq 0$?

To my understanding, if the only choice of $a_1, ...a_m \in \mathbb{F}$ that makes $a_1v_1 + ...+ a_mv_m$ equal $0$ is $a_1=...=a_m=0$, then the list $v1,...,v_m$ of vector $V$ is called linear independence.

If so, is it because zero vector itself also counts as one way to makes $a_1v_1 + ...+ a_mv_m$ equal $0$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take $v\in V$. If $a\in\mathbb F$, when do we have $av=0$?

- If $v\neq0$, that will happen only when $a=0$. Therefore, $\{v\}$ is linearly independent.
- If $v=0$ then, for instance, $1v=0$. Therefore $\{v\}$ is linearly dependent.

Answer (score 1):

If $v=0$, then $1\cdot v=0$ and since $1\neq 0$, $(v)$ is linearly dependent.

If $(v)$ is linearly dependent, then there exists $\lambda\in\mathbb{R}^*$ with $\lambda v=0$ and multiplying by $1/\lambda$ leads to $v=0$.

Answer (score 0):

If $v\neq 0$, then if there is $\alpha\in k$ ($k$ is the ground field) such that $\alpha v=0$, then if $\alpha=0$ we are done, if not: multiplying by $\alpha^{-1}$ we get that $0=\alpha^{-1}\cdot 0=\alpha^{-1}\cdot\left(\alpha v\right)=\left(\alpha^{-1}\alpha\right)v=1\cdot v=v\neq 0$. So that, $\left\lbrace v\right\rbrace$ is linealy independent.

On the other hand, if $v=0$, taking $\alpha=1$, we have that $\alpha v=0$, with $\alpha\neq 0$, then $\left\lbrace v\right\rbrace$ is linealy dependent.